# importing files in sas containing quotes

Tags: sas

I wanted to know how to import a SAS data file containing quotes (" ").

For example the file contains two variables:

```
 "gray or green", "blond"
 "ble", "red"
 "brown", "rou"
 "gray or green", "blond"
 "blue", "brown"
 "brown", "black"
 "gray or green", "black"
```

I tried the following code:

```
data color ; 
  infile 'file path' DLM = " , " ; 
  input v1 $ v2 $ ; 
  v1 label = "eyes colour" v2 = "hair colour"; 
run; 

proc print data = color; 
run;
```

Comment: For example the file contains two variables (v1 = eyes colour ,             v2 = hair colour) :
"gray or green", "blond",
"blue", "red",
"brown", "rou",
"gray or green", "blond",
"blue", "brown",
"brown", "black",
"gray or green", "black",

I tried the following code:

data color ;
infile 'file path' DLM = " , " ;
input v1 $ v2 $ ;
v1 label = "eyes colour" v2 = "hair colour";
run;
proc print data = color;
run;

Comment: you find attached the link to the file : http://www-math.univ-poitiers.fr/~phan/masterMMAS/documents/1m09/yeux-cheveux.txt Thank for your help

Comment: @Robert he did but in the comments. Please add your code to the question, not the comments.

Comment: @Reeza Thanks - I updated the question.

Comment: Sorry. I do not know where to post the code that's why.

Answer (score 2):

The format is CSV and you can use the DSD option to read the file.

> DSD specifies that when data values are enclosed in quotation marks, delimiters within the value are treated as character data. The DSD option changes how SAS treats delimiters when you use LIST input and sets the default delimiter to a comma. When you specify DSD, SAS treats two consecutive delimiters as a missing value and removes quotation marks from character values.

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm

```
data want;
infile cards DSD;
informat var1 var2 $20.;
input var1 $ var2 $;
cards;
"gray or green", "blond"
 "ble", "red"
 "brown", "rou"
 "gray or green", "blond"
 "blue", "brown"
 "brown", "black"
 "gray or green", "black"
 ;
 run;
```

Comment: The answer would be better with an explanation of what the DSD option does.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I'll try and see the result. Good day

Comment: Thank you for all your help